# How do `pass` and `listen` work in WriterT?

Tags: haskell

The code below probably isn't a good way to do this, but it's what I've managed to cobble together. Basically, I run a series of complex tasks, during which several things get logged. At the end of each one I dump the log into a .txt file and move on to the next batch in a loop.

To achieve this I make use of `listen` and `pass` in `WriterT` (as part of `RWST`). The code is below:

```
-- Miscelaneous stuff
newtype Log = Log [String]
type ConnectT a = EitherT String (RWST ConnectReader Log ConnectState IO) a

timeStampLog :: String -> Log
timeStampLog msg = do
    theTime <- liftIO $ fmap zonedTimeToLocalTime getZonedTime
    let msgStart = show theTime ++ ": "
    tell $ Log [msgStart ++ msg]

logToFileIO :: Log -> IO ()
logToFileIO (Log xs) = appendFile "Log.txt" $ "\r\n" ++ intercalate "\r\n" (reverse xs)
---------------------


logToFile :: ConnectT a -> ConnectT ()
logToFile cta = let ctaw = listen cta
                in  pass $ do
                                (_,w) <- ctaw
                                liftIO $ logToFileIO w
                                return ((),const mempty)

mapFunction :: (Show a) => a -> ConnectT ()
mapFunction a = logToFile $ do
    timeStampLog $ "Starting sequence for " ++ show a
    lotsOfLogging a
    timeStampLog $ "Finishing sequence for " ++ show a

loopFunction :: ConnectT ()
loopFunction = logToFile $ do
    timeStampLog "Starting Loop"
    mapM_ mapFunction someList
    timeStampLog "Finishing Loop"
```

What I end up with is something like this:

```
2015-03-17 20:21:40.8198823: Starting sequence for a
2015-03-17 20:21:41.8198823: (logs for a)
2015-03-17 20:21:41.8198823: Finishing sequence for a
2015-03-17 20:21:41.8198823: Starting sequence for b
2015-03-17 20:21:42.8198823: (logs for b)
2015-03-17 20:21:42.8198823: Finishing sequence for b
2015-03-17 20:21:39.8198823: Starting Loop
2015-03-17 20:21:42.8198823: Finishing Loop
```

Where the log entry for starting/finishing the loop end up together at the end.

I'm not entirely surprised that the call to `logToFile` in `mapFunction` doesn't include the log information from the `loopFunction` as the information hasn't passed to it via a bind.

But I'm still having trouble understanding how `pass` and `listen` work. And also how I would go about fixing this (admittedly minor) issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can determine how `listen` and `pass` work almost entirely from their types. We'll start with listen.

#### listen

```
listen :: (Monoid w, Monad m) => RWST r w s m a -> RWST r w s m (a, w)
```

Unwrapping the `RWST` we have

```
listen :: (Monoid w, Monad m) => (r -> s -> m (a, s, w)) -> r -> s -> m ((a, w), s, w)
```

It needs to return an `m ...`. The only way we have to make `m`s is to `return` something or apply the input function to an `r`and an `s` (we can't use `>>=` since it requires we already have an `m`). We don't have an `a` to return so we have to apply the function to an `r` and `s`. There's only one `r` and `s` we can use, those passed into the result.

```
listen k r s = ... (k r s)
```

Now we have an `m (a, s, w)` but need an `m ((a, w), s, w)`. We can run the action again to get another `m` (nonsense for "`listen`ing") or do something with the `(a, s, w)` inside the  `m` with `>>=`.

```
listen k r s = k r s >>= \(a, s' w) -> ...
```

To use `bind` we need an `m`. We can either return something or apply the input function to an `r` and `s` and repeat the action again, which is  nonsense for "`listen`ing". We `return` something.

```
listen k r s = k r s >>= \(a, s', w) -> return ...
```

We need an `a`, a `w`, an `s`, and another `w`. We only have one `a` and no way to get any others.

```
listen k r s = k r s >>= \(a, s', w) -> return ((a,...),...,...)
```

There are 3 ways we can get a `w`: `mempty`, the `w` from the result of the action, or combining two `w`s together with `<>`. Returning `mempty` is pointless; the user could have just used `mempty` themselves. Duplicating what was logged with `<>` is as much nonsense as running an action twice, so we *return what was logged by the first action*.

```
listen k r s = k r s >>= \(a, s', w) -> return ((a,w),...,...)
```

We have two `s` es: `s` and `s'`. Reverting the state changes of the action is nonsense for "`listen`ing", so we return the changed state `s'`.

```
listen k r s = k r s >>= \(a, s', w) -> return ((a,w),s',...)
```

Now we are faced with the only interesting choice: what `w` should we keep for what was logged? The user has "`listen`ed" for what was logged; we could say that it's their problem now and reset the log to `mempty`. But "`listen`ing" doesn't suggest that it should change what something does, it should only observe it. Therefore, we keep the resulting log `w` intact.

```
listen k r s = k r s >>= \(a, s', w) -> return ((a,w),s',w)
```

If we wrap this in its `RWST`s again we have

```
listen m = RWST \r s -> (runRWST m) r s >>= \(a, s', w) -> return ((a,w),s',w)
```

All we did was run the input action and include what it logged along with its resulting `a` in the result as a tuple. This matches the [documentation for `listen`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-RWS-Lazy.html#v:listen):

> `listen m` is an action that executes the action `m` and adds its output to the value of the computation.
>
> ```
> runRWST (listen m) r s = liftM (\ (a, w) -> ((a, w), w)) (runRWST m r s)
> ```

#### tell

```
pass :: (Monoid w, Monad m) => RWST r w s m (a, w -> w) -> RWST r w s m a
```

We begin as before, unwrapping the `RWST`

```
pass :: (Monoid w, Monad m) => (r -> s -> m ((a, w->w), s, w)) -> r -> s -> m (a, s, w)
```

We follow the same argument for how to get a resulting `m` as we used for `listen`

```
pass k r s = ... (k r s)
```

Now we have an `m ((a, w->w), s, w))` but need an `m (a, s, w)`. We can run the action again to get another `m` (nonsense for "`pass`ing") or do something with the `((a, w->w), s, w)` inside the `m` with `>>=`.

```
pass k r s = k r s >>= \((a, f), s', w) -> ...
```

To use `bind` we need an `m`. We can either return something or apply the input function to an `r` and `s` and repeat the action again, which is  nonsense for "`pass`ing". We `return` something.

```
pass k r s = k r s >>= \((a, f), s', w) -> return ...
```

We need an `a`, an `s`, and a `w`. We only have one `a` and no way to get any others.

```
pass k r s = k r s >>= \((a, f), s', w) -> return (a,...,...)
```

We have two `s` es: `s` and `s'`. Reverting the state changes of the action is nonsense for "`pass`ing", so we return the changed state `s'`.

```
pass k r s = k r s >>= \((a, f), s', w) -> return (a,s',...)
```

There are 4 ways we can get a `w`: `mempty`, the `w` from the result of the action, combining two `w`s together with `<>`, or applying the function `f` to another `w`. Setting the result to `mempty` leaves us wondering why the user provided a function `f :: w -> w`. themselves. Duplicating what was logged with `<>` is as much nonsense as running an action twice. We should be applying the function `f` to something.

```
pass k r s = k r s >>= \((a, f), s', w) -> return (a,s',f ...)
```

We could apply `f` to something built from `mempty`s and `<>`, but if that were the case all of the `f`s would be equivalent to `const ...`; the type for it might as well have been a `w`. We could apply `f` to some elaborate structure built from `w`, `mempty`, `<>`, and `f`, but all of those structures could have been defined in `f` itself if we simply *pass* it `w`.

```
pass k r s = k r s >>= \((a, f), s', w) -> return (a,s',f w)
```

If we wrap this in its `RWST`s again we have

```
pass m = RWST \r s -> (runRWST k) r s >>= \((a, f), s', w) -> return (a,s',f w)
```

We ran the input action and changed what was logged by the function that was a result of the action. This matches the [documentation for `pass`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-RWS-Lazy.html#v:pass):

> `pass m` is an action that executes the action `m`, which returns a value and a function, and returns the value, applying the function to the output.
>
> ```
> runRWST (pass m) r s = liftM (\ ((a, f), w) -> (a, f w)) (runRWST m r s)
> ```

Comment: But where does that `w` from `(a, f w)` come from? e.g. with `State s` the `s` is threaded around: `modify (\_ -> x) >>= get` but there is no equivalent with `Writer`. So because there's no original `w` that gets passed at `runRWST` does that mean it uses a local `mempty` for each Monadic computation and then `<>` them together, instead of threading around the `w` as happens with `State`?

Comment: @TheCriticalImperitive That's exactly what it has to do; there's no sensible alternative.

Comment: I suppose it's pretty obvious now that you've explained it to me. Thanks for taking the time to write that out. It just wasn't clicking for me when I read that documentation, but when it's spelled out it's obvious that there's no alternative.

Comment: `WriterT` is the wrong tool for logging. I'm writing another answer describing the right tool.

Answer (score 1):

The existing `WriterT w m` can't perform any action in the underlying `m` to perform logging until after the action has been run and the `w` has been assembled. As your question illustrates, this is confusing. The log for the `do` block `loopFunction` isn't written by `logToFile` until after the `do` block itself finishes running.

#### LoggerT

Let's invent a new `WriterT` called `LoggerT`. Our new `LoggerT` is going to provide a new function

```
logTells :: (Monoid w, Monoid w', Monad m) =>
            (w -> LoggerT w' m ()) -> LoggerT w m a -> LoggerT w' m a
```

The intuition behind this is: we'll be able to provide an action (with type `w -> LoggerT w' m ()`) to log every `tell`, replacing the logged result with the result of the action. If we smash two things the user `tell`s us together with `<>` we'll no longer be able to log both of them; we'll only ever be able to log the result of `<>`. Since our `LoggerT` will never be able to use `<>` it will never need the `Monoid` instances. We must drop the `Monoid` constraint from everything in `LoggerT`.

```
logTells :: (Monad m) =>
            (w -> LoggerT w' m ()) -> LoggerT w m a -> LoggerT w' m a
```

We need to remember every `tell` so that we can replace it later. But when we replace it "later", the logging should happen at the point the `tell` appeared in the code. For example, if we make

```
processX :: LoggerT String m ()
processX = do
    tell "Starting process X"
    lotsOfProcessing
    tell "Finishing process X"
```

And then "later" write `logTells logToFile processX` we want the resulting computation to look like the following.

```
logTells logToFile processX = do
    logToFile "Starting process X"
    lotsOfProcessing
    logToFile "Finishing process X"
```

None of `lotsOfProcessing` should happen until the `logToFile` for `tell "Starting process X"` has already happened. This means that when the user `tell`s us something we need to remember not only what we were told, but everything that happens after that. We "remember" things in the constructor for a `data`.

```
data LoggerT w m a
    = Tell w (LoggerT w m a)
    | ...

tell :: w -> LoggerT w m ()
tell w = Tell w (return ())
```

We also need to be able to perform actions in the underlying `Monad`. It would be tempting to add another constructor `Lift (m a)`, but then we couldn't decide what to log as a result of the underlying computation. Instead, we'll let it decide the entire future `LoggerT w m a` to run.

```
data LoggerT w m a
    = Tell w    (LoggerT w m a)
    | M      (m (LoggerT w m a))
    ...
```

If we try to `lift` an underlying computation `m a` into `LoggerT` we now have a problem; we don't have a way to turn the `a` into a `LoggerT w m a` to put it in the `M` constructor.

```
instance MonadTrans (LoggerT w m) where
    lift ma = M (??? ma)
```

We could try `lift`ing `return` from the underlying `Monad`, but that's just a circular definition. We'll add another constructor for `Return`ing.

```
data LoggerT w m a
    = Tell   w    (LoggerT w m a)
    | M        (m (LoggerT w m a))
    | Return    a

instance MonadTrans (LoggerT w m) where
    lift = M . liftM Return
```

To finish our monad transformer, we'll write a `Monad` instance.

```
instance Monad m => Monad (LoggerT w m) where
    return = Return
    la0 >>= k = go la0
         where
             go (Tell w la ) = Tell w (go la)
             go (M      mla) = M      (liftM go mla)
             go (Return a  ) = Return a
```

We can now define `logTells`. It replaces every `Tell` with the action to perform to log it.

```
logTells :: (w -> LoggerT w' m ()) -> LoggerT w m a -> LoggerT w' m a
logTells k = go
    where
        go (Tell w la ) = k w >> go la
        go (M      mla) = M      (liftM go mla)
        go (Return a)   = return a
```

Finally, we'll provide a way to get out of `LoggerT` by replacing all of the `Tell`s with an action, very similar to `logTells` but dropping the `LoggerT` from the result.
Since it will get rid of the `LoggerT` we'll call it `runLoggerT` and swap the arguments to match the convention of other transformers.

```
runLoggerT :: LoggerT w m a -> (w -> m ()) -> m a
runLoggerT la0 k = go la0
    where
        go (Tell w la ) = k w >> go la
        go (M      mla) =        liftM go mla
        go (Return a)   =        return a
```

`LoggerT` already exists, we don't need to write it ourself. It's the [`Producer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.4/docs/Pipes-Core.html#t:Producer) from the very mature [pipes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes) library.

#### pipes

The `Producer` from the pipes library is the correct logging transformer.

```
type Producer b = Proxy X () () b
```

Every [`Proxy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.4/docs/Pipes.html#t:Proxy) has a `MonadTrans (Proxy a' a b' b)` instance and a `Monad m => Monad (Proxy a' a b' b m)` instance.

We `tell` it what to log with [`yield`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.4/docs/Pipes.html#v:yield).

```
yield :: Monad m => a -> Producer' a m ()

tell = yield
```

When we know what we want to do with the `yield`s, we replace them with what we want to do using [`for`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.4/docs/Pipes.html#v:for).

```
for :: Monad m =>
             Proxy x' x b' b m a' ->
       (b -> Proxy x' x c' c m b')   
          -> Proxy x' x c' c m a'
```

Specialized for `Producer` and `()`, `for` has the type

```
for :: Monad m => 
             Producer b m a   ->
       (b -> Producer c m ()) ->
             Producer c m a

logTells = flip for
```

If we replace each of the `yield`s with an action in the underlying monad, we won't have anything produced anymore and can run the `Proxy` with [`runEffect`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.4/docs/Pipes.html#v:runEffect).

```
runEffect :: Monad m => Effect             m r -> m r
runEffect :: Monad m => Proxy    X () () X m r -> m r
runEffect :: Monad m => Producer         X m r -> m r

runLoggerT la0 k = runEffect $ for la0 (lift . k)
```

We can even recover the `WriterT` with [`hoist`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html#t:MFunctor) which replaces the underlying monad (every `Proxy a' a b' b` has an `MFunctor` instance).

```
hoist :: (Monad m, MFunctor t) => (forall a. m a -> n a) -> t m b -> t n b
```

We use `hoist` to replace the underlying monad with `WriterT w m` by `lift`ing each `m a` into `WriterT w m a`. Then we replace each `yield` with `lift . tell`, and run the result.

```
toWriterT :: (Monad m, Monoid w) => Producer w m r -> WriterT w m r
toWriterT p0 = runEffect $ for (hoist lift p0) (lift . tell)

toWriterT p0 = runLoggerT      (hoist lift p0)         tell
```

`Producer` is essentially the free `WriterT` that doesn't require a `Monoid` for the items being written.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified, but definitely real-life example that uses `censor` (which is defined in terms of `pass` as

```
censor :: (MonadWriter w m) => (w -> w) -> m a -> m a
censor f m = pass $ (,f) <$> m
```

) to collect free variables of a lambda term:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set

type VarId = String

data Term = Var VarId
          | Lam VarId Term
          | App Term Term

freeVars :: Term -> Set VarId
freeVars = execWriter . go
  where
    go :: Term -> Writer (Set VarId) ()
    go (Var x) = tell $ Set.singleton x
    go (App f e) = go f >> go e
    go (Lam x e) = censor (Set.delete x) $ go e
```

Now, of course you can implement this without all the `Writer` machinery, but remember this is just a simplified example standing in for some more involved compilation/analysis function, where tracking free variables is just one of the things going on.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is clear enough? http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Writer-Lazy.html#g:1

Examples (run the following in ghci)

```
import Control.Monad.Writer

runWriterT ( do (a,w) <- listen $ do { tell "foo" ; return 42 } ; tell $ reverse w ; return a )

    ==> (42,"foooof")

runWriterT ( pass $ do { tell "foo" ; return (42,reverse) } )

    ==> (42,"oof")
```